# Sending a DM to people who react to message - Discord JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to send a message to the first 5 people who react to the message, however it only sends a DM to the first person who reacted and does not allow anyone else to react or receive a DM.

How would I do this?

```js
case 'await':
  message.channel.sendMessage('React for dm').then(sentMessage => {
    sentMessage.react('1️⃣').then(() => sentMessage.react('2️⃣'));

    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
      return ['1️⃣', '2️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
    };

    sentMessage.awaitReactions(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: 60000,
        errors: ['time']
      })
      .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣') {
          message.author.sendMessage('I told you I would!')
        }
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `max: 1` That tells the collector to quit after it has successfully collected 1 reaction.  You should set that to 5.

After that you need to loop through the `collected` to send a DM to all of them rather than using first().